# Objective equivalent to AppleScript : Opening directory without bringing every finder window to from

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, finder

There this AppleScript

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to set index of window 1 to 1
do shell script "open /Volumes"
```

Which opens a directory in Finder without bringing every onther Finder windows to the front.

Currently I'm using :

```
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:fileURL];
```

But it has the flaw to bring every Finder windows on the top of others.

Any idea how I could achieve the same behaviour as the AppleScript ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [NSAppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsapplescript_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAppleScript/initWithSource%3a) to run applescript code in Objective-C if Cocoa doesn't provide the functionality you want.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but was looking for something not calling the AppleScript.

Comment: If `NSWorkspace` doesn't provide a method for opening just 1 window without bringing every finder window into focus then I doubt you can do it with Cocoa. You can always use code injection if you don't want to resort to applescript, but that seems way too overkill for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, `-[NSWorkspace openURL:]` also sends the application an `activate` event whereas the `open` process does not.

I'd recommend looking into the [LaunchServices](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) API. It's what both `NSWorkspace` and `open` use behind the scenes, but gives you more control than `NSWorkspace`'s limited API.

--

p.s. If you do have to call out to `open` (or any other command line tool) from ObjC, you should use Cocoa's `NSTask`. (AppleScript's `do shell script` command is just its [crappy] equivalent of `NSTask`.)